# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token usando $http.get()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, ionic-framework, vscode

estoy intentando obtener una lista a través de una url usando el método `GET`, pero me genera un error muy confuso, ya que es primera vez que lo veo.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Me dice que tengo el error en la siguiente linea

```
grupos.$inject = ['$http'];

function grupos($http){

    function obtenerGrupos(){

        var url;

        url = 'http://localhost:1890/Grupos1';

        return {
            $http.get(url);
        };

    };

    return {
        obtenerGrupos: obtenerGrupos
    };

}
```

Según el editor que uso, VS Code, me dice que debo colocar dos puntos **:** en vez de un punto **.**. Y si coloco para probar a ver que sucede, me dice esto.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

[image: error http.get]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy obvio el error, estas retornando un objeto `return {...}`, no puedes ingresar `;` dentro de un objeto pues no es una sintaxis válida, cada campo-valor se separa por coma. Además te falta el literal

```
return {
    nombre: $http.get(url)
//  ^^^^^^ esto  
}
```

Comment: Si tienes razón lo pude resolver, gracias